# Cryptic clue with cryptic clues inside

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

> English [artist to burn, burns heart] (6) [bits of nazis covering animal] (6) dollar with [familiar comrades, abbreviated, with the console] (7) residing on [forest endless street, rearranged] (5) (7)

What's it called?

Hint:

> The abbreviation can take several letters from the word. The word you need is abbreviation as well.

Comment: Been poking at the 'familiar comrades' cryptic to maybe help M Oehm out, to no avail. Can we get a small hint in a little while if not one gets it?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I changed the definition. Sorry, this is my first cryptic so mistakes were to be made

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From M Oehm's answer we know the final cryptic is

> English [singer] [shares] dollar with [Famicon] residing on [trees] (7)

The solution is

> NESTING (NES and STING sharing the S).

Comment: Yeah! I thought you would also note how this answer relates to the puzzle structure, but still nice! Tick for you.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Aah I see what you mean... Nice!

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer

The parts in square brackets are ...

> ... cryptic clues. The numbers are the enumerations, i.e. the length of the answers.

artist to burn, burns heart (6)

> SINGER (artist) = SINGE (burns) + heart of (bu)R(ns)

bits of nazis covering animal (6)

> SHARES (bits) = HARE (animal) in SS (Nazis) (not really sure here)

familiar comrades, abbreviated, with <s>same abbreviation</s> the console (7)

> [FAMICOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Entertainment_System) (console) = "abbreviations" of FAMI(liar) COM(rades)

forest endless street, rearranged (5)

> TREES (forest) = anagram of STREE(t)* without its end

Filling these in, we get:

> English [singer] [shares] dollar with [Famicon] residing on [trees] (7)
>
>  I think this is another cryptc clue that leads to the final answer. If so, it sure has an awkward surface and I bet that Famicon means NES, which uses up three of the seven letters. There are short tree names (OAKS, ELMS), but if the def. is English singer, the dollar is unaccounted for.

Comment: Could the familiar comrades also mean friends?

Comment: Hm. I don't really see it. What is friends an abbreviation of? Also note that the clues has been changed to "... with the console".

Comment: Friends as an abbreviation can be noticed here: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2320a9f29250a073a40bdb9a5f4d6a11

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @M Oehm 's answer,

> The familiar comrades may mean FRIENDS as it is an abbreviation also

So the final answer is

> ENGLISH SINGER SHARES DOLLAR WITH FRIENDS RESIDING ON TREES

Comment: friends abbreviated can be rot13(sq be sqf)